# how to login in the same form for admin and user

Tags: javascript, php

1.How can i login in same form for admin and user?

Here is my code

```
    <?php
include('config.php'); 
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$salt = sha1(md5($password));
$password = md5($password.$salt);
$sql="SELECT email FROM registered_members WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];            
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$sql1="SELECT email,password FROM admin WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$active1=$row1['active'];            
$count_admin=mysql_num_rows($result1);
if($count==1){
session_register("email");
session_register("password");     
$_SESSION['login_user']=$email;
header("location:member.php"); 
}
elseif($count_admin==1){
session_register("email");
session_register("password");     
$_SESSION['login_admin']=$email;
header("location:admincp/admin-panel.php"); 
}
else {
echo "Wrong email or Password";
}}
?>
```

2.Please help me how can i resolve this??

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Why do you have two different table for this? Why not just put an `is_admin` field into your members table?

Comment: what will be the code if i put a is_admin field in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please use some indentation before post. It's hard and hardly someone will answer you with a dirty code
2. As the comment said, SQL Injections. Prevent them and learn about prepared statements:
   http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Before your answer, is it really need two tables to have the same content? Wouldn't be easier to create a single column that could mark if user has administrator rights or not? It would prevent you to run two queries, faster code, faster performance, less memory consumption.

Now, your question:

`Code removed`

Please have in mind your code structure and safety.

Comment: Do not post insecure code on StackOverflow.  People blindly copy/paste this stuff all the time.  Also, consider using something other than `md5()` for password hashing.  The salt method is also flawed... reversing one hash will reveal the password for all other identical passwords, since the salt is based on the password.  The logic, is a mess.  Why not join these tables?  Finally, your `Location:` headers need to contain a full URL to be valid.  Most browsers will let you get away with it, and a new proposed standard is to not require it, but for now you still need the full URL.

Comment: The question wasn't about security. The question was about how to put two session values and the error was in a conditional chain. If people blindly copy/paste, the they should be aware of what they are doing. Also, this is a really specific case, it's not general code. Have in mind that I don't like to post insecure code, but this is not the meaning of the question.

Comment: so meaning if i use method post without pdo hackers can easily hack my mysql database. what if my server has a ssl am i open to mysql injection?

Comment: SSL wont protect up from MySQL Injection. What you need is to prevent that input values could change your query and run something that shouldn't.

Comment: if i use pdo then my md5 password can't be reverse?

Comment: @FabianoAraujo It doesn't matter what the question was about, specifically.  Show good examples in your code, to accelerate learning for everyone using your answer.

Comment: @user3303166 You're confusing several concepts.  There is no one thing to do to secure everything.  Using prepared/parameterized queries disambiguates the command (your SQL) from the data (your variables used in the query).  Without separating those two, it's possible for someone to use some data to inject a command.  All of your other security problems still exist.

Comment: The problems isn't your MD5. For example, if $password is populated by $_POST['password'] and someone, in your form that send this values to process, try a SQL Injection, simple putting as value: '; SHOW TABLES; It can be processed and as a result, the final user receive a list of all tables. This is the meaning of injection, to allow the final user to manipulate your query and run other queries.  PDO isn't that hard to implement. Why that resistence?

Comment: @FabianoAraujo so that means my post method is unsecure?

Comment: @user3303166 It means that the way you run the SQL query from PHP is insecure.

Comment: what if i use rows instead of post will my database secure?

Comment: @user3303166 No. The change that must to be done are prepared statements. If you search more about SQL Injection on PHP, you will understand the concept.